# Help me with this sum: $\sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{n}{\log^2\left(\frac{n}{5^i}\right)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

I have to prove something but I'm stuck, I ended up with this sum. Is there any transformation I can do in the following sum?
$$\sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{n}{\log^2\left(\frac{n}{5^i}\right)}$$

Comment: Is the question "is there any transformation I can do in the following sum?"? Because then the (not very interesting) answer is: Yes you can.

Comment: Please add some of your work so far!

Comment: Yes that's the question, if you have any transformatio

Comment: I guess you are looking for straight answers instead of a detailed derivation of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac1{\ln\bigg(\dfrac n{a^k}\bigg)^2}=\frac{\psi^{(1)}\big(-\log_an\big)}{\ln^2a}$ , see [polygamma function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygamma_function) for more details. For $n=1$, if the sum starts at $k=1$, the result is $\dfrac{\zeta(2)}{\ln^2a}=\dfrac{\pi^2}{6\ln^2a}$ , see [Basel problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem). Both expressions are derived by using some basic properties of the logarithmic function, such as $\ln\dfrac ab=\ln a-\ln b$, and $\ln a^b=$ $=b\ln a$, etc.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
A *$\ul{detailed}$ derivation* is given below:

> \begin{align}
> \color{#00f}{\large\sum_{i = 0}^{\infty}{n \over \ln^{2}\pars{n/5^i}}}&=
> n\sum_{i = 0}^{\infty}{1 \over \bracks{\ln\pars{n} - \ln\pars{5}i}^{2}}
> ={n \over \ln^{2}\pars{5}}
> \sum_{i = 0}^{\infty}{1 \over \braces{\bracks{-\ln\pars{n}/\ln\pars{5}} + i}^{2}}
> \\[3mm]&=\color{#00f}{\large%
> {n \over \ln^{2}\pars{5}}\,\Psi'\pars{-\,{\ln\pars{n} \over \ln\pars{5}}}}\,,
> \qquad{-\,{\ln\pars{n} \over \ln\pars{5}}}\not=0,-1,-2,\ldots
> \end{align}

where $\ds{\Psi'\pars{z}}$ is the [Trigamma Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygamma_function). See ${\bf 6.4.10}$ in
[this table](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_260.htm).

Comment: @user147382 I guess you are looking for straight answers instead of a detailed derivation of it.